# What is Sliding Window Algorithm? Examples?

Tags: algorithm, sliding-window

While solving a geometry problem, I came across an approach called Sliding Window Algorithm.

Couldn't really find any study material/details on it.

What is the algorithm about?

Comment: Are you talking about [this kind of windows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function) ? I don't see the link with geometry.

Comment: Explaining the connection won't be possible unless you describe the geometry problem.

Comment: No, we're talking about this type of window: https://www.plygem.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/T3_Horizontal_Slider.gif

Comment: Here is an example: https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-substring-without-repeating-characters

Answer (score 236, accepted):

Generally speaking a sliding window is a sub-list that runs over an underlying collection. I.e., if you have an array like

```
[a b c d e f g h]
```

a sliding window of size 3 would run over it like

```
[a b c]
  [b c d]
    [c d e]
      [d e f]
        [e f g]
          [f g h]
```

This is useful if you for instance want to compute a running average, or if you want to create a set of all adjacent pairs etc.

Comment: Hi ,I have a question about sliding window. For example, I have 1 year of information and I am using a 4 month window to analyse it. There are variables that change throughout time. If I am analysing 4 months in the middle of the year, do I use the window size to calculate the metrics for the 4 months, or do I use the variable value at the end of the window that corresponds to 6 or 7 months of information calculated? In this case I am refering to a variable that grows one month at a time.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear, but suppose you have the following situation: `[5, 10, 7, 13, 19, 14, 3, 13, 17, 10, 22, 2]` for January, February, ..., December. If your window size is 4, the middle of the year will have this window: `[19, 14, 3, 13]`. That's all. If you're calculating a running average for example, the average at the middle of the year would be `(19+14+3+13)/4`. Did this answer your question?

Comment: It certainly gave me more insight. I would like to extend by giving this example: there are 6 months and 3 clients. Client no.1 exists from the beggining, client no.2 appears on the third month and client no.3 appears on the fifth month. The idea would be to use a sliding window to calculate a monthly mean for example. My question is since the sliding window moves a month, the mean for the clients will varies if the window catches months in which they are present in all of them? If not clear I can elaborate.

Answer (score 461):

I think of it as more a technique than an algorithm. It's a technique that could be utilized in various algorithms.

I think the technique is best understood with the following example. Imagine we have this array:

```
[ 5, 7, 1, 4, 3, 6, 2, 9, 2 ]
```

How would we find the largest sum of five consecutive elements? Well, we'd first look at `5, 7, 1, 4, 3` and see that the sum is `20`. Then we'd look at the next set of five consecutive elements, which is `7, 1, 4, 3, 6`. The sum of those is `21`. This is more than our previous sum, so `7, 1, 4, 3, 6` is currently the best we've got so far.

Let's see if we could improve. `1, 4, 3, 6, 2`? No, that sums to `16`. `4, 3, 6, 2, 9`? That sums to `24`, so now that's the best sequence we've got. Now we move along to the next sequence, `3, 6, 2, 9, 2`. That one sums to `22`, which doesn't beat our current best of `24`. And we've reached the end, so we're done.

The brute force approach to implementing this programmatically is as follows:

```js
const getMaxSumOfFiveContiguousElements = (arr) => {
  let maxSum = -Infinity;
  let currSum;

  for (let i = 0; i <= arr.length - 5; i++) {
    currSum = 0;

    for (let j = i; j < i + 5; j++) {
      currSum += arr[j];
    }

    maxSum = Math.max(maxSum, currSum);
  }

  return maxSum;
};
```

What is the time complexity of this? It's `O(n*k)`. The outer loop is going through `n - k + 1` items, but when `n` is much larger than `k`, we can forget about the `k + 1` part and just call it `n` items. Then the inner loop is going through `k` items, so we have `O(n*k)`. Try visualizing it like this:

[image]

Can we get this down to just `O(n)`? Let's return to this array:

```
[ 5, 7, 1, 4, 3, 6, 2, 9, 2 ]
```

First we get the sum of `5, 7, 1, 4, 3`. Next we need the sum of `7, 1, 4, 3, 6`. Visualize it like this, with a "window" surrounding each group of five elements.

[image]

What's the difference between the first window and the second window? Well, the second window got rid of the `5` on the left but added a `6` on the right. So since we know the sum of the first window was `20`, to get the sum of the second window, we take that `20`, subtract out the `5`, and add the `6` to get `21`. We don't actually have to go through each element in the second window and add them up (`7 + 1 + 4 + 3 + 6`). That would involve doing repeated and unnecessary work.

Here the sliding window approach ends up being two operations instead of five, since `k` is `5`. That's not a huge improvement, but you can imagine that for larger `k` (and larger `n`) it really does help.

[image]

Here's how the code would work using the sliding window technique:

```js
const getLargestSumOfFiveConsecutiveElements = (arr) => {
  let currSum = getSum(arr, 0, 4);
  let largestSum = currSum;

  for (let i = 1; i <= arr.length - 5; i++) {
    currSum -= arr[i - 1]; // subtract element to the left of curr window
    currSum += arr[i + 4]; // add last element in curr window
    largestSum = Math.max(largestSum, currSum);
  }

  return largestSum;
};

const getSum = (arr, start, end) => {
  let sum = 0;

  for (let i = start; i <= end; i++) {
    sum += arr[i];
  }

  return sum;
};
```

And that's the gist of the sliding window technique. In other problems you may be doing something more complicated than getting the sum of the elements inside the window. Or the window itself may be of varying size instead of the fixed size of five that we saw here. But this basic application of the sliding window technique should give you a foundation from which you could build off of.

Comment: Amazing illustrations. Thank you for taking the time to do this.

Comment: @Ezio I really appreciate the compliment, thank you. Figuring out illustrations like these is really something I have to do for myself in order to understand it :)

Comment: Absolutely. We are computer programmers but we have to master the art of problem-solving using pen and paper.

Comment: In the second illustration, shouldn't the golden dot be in second. slide? (1st index instead of 0) or am I missing something?

Comment: @TJ The first row in the second illustration represents `let currSum = getSum(arr, 0, 4);`. So, the sum of the first five dots. Then from there, to slide the window, we're 1) subtracting the dot in the first column and 2) adding the dot in the sixth column, so that's why the the dots in the first and sixth columns are lit up for the second row.

Comment: @AdamZerner What tools do you use to make these visualizations?

Comment: @PartOfTheOhana I used [Sketch](https://www.sketch.com/) which is kind of a lightweight version of Photoshop. As an alternative, I recently came across [Excalidraw](https://excalidraw.com/) which is free and also seems like a good option for visualizations like this.

Comment: @AdamZerner At the first code snippet where you have `for (let j = i; j <= i + 5; j++) ` isn't the loop runs 6 times? We need to run 5 times right?

Comment: This should be accepted answer

Comment: @AdamZerner 10/10, this illustration is very helpful. With this level of clarity, I think you should write a book on design & DS.

Answer (score 67):

The Sliding window is a problem-solving technique for problems that involve arrays/lists. These problems are easy to solve using a brute force approach in O(n^2) or O(n^3).  **Using the 'sliding window' technique, we can reduce the time complexity to O(n).**

Great article on this is here: https://medium.com/outco/how-to-solve-sliding-window-problems-28d67601a66

> So the first thing you want to be able to do is to identify a problem
>   that uses a sliding window paradigm. Luckily, there are some common
>   giveaways:
>
> - The problem will involve a data structure that is ordered and iterable like an array or a string
> - You are looking for some subrange in that array/string, like the longest, shortest or target value.
> - There is an apparent naive or brute force solution that runs in O(N²), O(2^N) or some other large time complexity.
>
> But the biggest giveaway is that the thing you are looking for is
>   often some kind of optimal, like the longest sequence or shortest
>   sequence of something that satisfies a given condition exactly.

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer - the other answers are about "convolution" rather than about this sliding window algorithm.

Answer (score 20):

To add to the previous answers here are some more resources which illustrates this concept very well.

[This youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MK-NZ4hN7rs) is the best that I have found on this topic.

[Here](https://leetcode.com/problemset/all/?topicSlugs=sliding-window) are the list of questions on leetcode which can be solved using this technique

The sliding window is one of the most frequent topic which is asked in the coding rounds in the top companies so it is definitely worth spending some time to master this.

Answer (score 3):

In general, sliding window is technical use to reduce nested loop and increase performance for operation.
How it works?

Think about it like range of windows in the bus, each window will maintain an element, and after move window to next element, recalculate window condition again, until this window satisfy target of problem.

***The art of sliding window technical is keep previous calculation to avoid recalculate again, and this will help reduce complexity of code from O(n^2) to O(n).***

For example, find the maximum of k consecutive numbers in array:

array = [4, 9, 2, -1, 0, 7]

k = 3

result: maxSum = 15

**I. Let do first with naive Approach( O(n*k) ):**

```
func findMaxSumKConsecutiveNumbers(array: [Int], k: Int) -> Int {
  
  var maxSum = Int.min
  for i in 0..<(array.count - k + 1) {
    var sum: Int = 0
    for j in i..<(i+k) {
      sum = sum + array[j]
    }
    if sum > maxSum {
      maxSum = sum
    }
  }
  return maxSum
}
```

**---------------------------------**

**II. Then use sliding window technical (O(n)):**

[image: the window with size is 31]

In above image, after each of moving, the windowSum will recalculate again by:

> - Subtract previous value and add new value: windowSum = windowSum + 7 - 2

Coding:

```
func findMaxSumKConsecutiveNumbersUsingSlidingWindow(array: [Int], k: Int) -> Int {
  var windowSum = 0
  // Calculate first window value
  for i in 0..<k {
    windowSum = windowSum + array[i]
  }
  var maxSum = Int.min
  for i in 1..<(array.count - k + 1) {
    if windowSum > maxSum {
      maxSum = windowSum
    }
    windowSum = windowSum + array[i + k - 1] - array[i - 1]
    
  }
  return maxSum
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer I have ever seen, Thanks