# Java: Find the longest substring without any number and at least one upper case character

Tags: java, string, algorithm, data-structures

Came across a programming exercise and was stuck. The problem is:

> You need to define a valid password for an email but the only
>   restrictions are:
>
> - The password must contain one uppercase character
> - The password should not have numeric digit
>
>   Now, given a String, find the length of the longest substring which
>     is a valid password.   For e.g `Input Str = "a0Ba"` , the output should
>     be 2 as "Ba" is the valid substring.

I used the concept of longest substring without repeating characters which I already did before but was unable to modify it to find the solution to above problem. My code for longest substring without repeating characters is:

```
public int lengthOfLongestSubstring(String s) {
    int n = s.length();
    Set<Character> set = new HashSet<>();
    int ans = 0, i = 0, j = 0;
    while (i < n && j < n) {
        // try to extend the range [i, j]
        if (!set.contains(s.charAt(j))){
            set.add(s.charAt(j++));
            ans = Math.max(ans, j - i);
        }
        else {
            set.remove(s.charAt(i++));
        }
    }
    return ans;
}
```

Comment: If you want to do it in an elegant manner, use `regex`. Search on google about `Pattern.matches()` and regex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about

```
final String input = "a0Ba";

final int answer = Arrays.stream(input.split("[0-9]+"))
    .filter(s -> s.matches("(.+)?[A-Z](.+)?"))
    .sorted((s1, s2) -> s2.length() - s1.length())
    .findFirst()
    .orElse("")
    .length();

out.println(answer);
```

`Arrays.stream(input.split("[0-9]+"))` splits the original string into an array of strings. The separator is any sequence of numbers (numbers aren't allowed so they serve as separators). Then, a stream is created so I can apply functional operations and transformations.

`.filter(s -> s.matches("(.+)?[A-Z](.+)?"))` keeps into the stream only strings that have at least one upper-case letter.

`.sorted((s1, s2) -> s2.length() - s1.length())` sorts the stream by length (desc).

`.findFirst()` tries to get the first string of the stream.

`.orElse("")` returns an empty string if no string was found.

`.length();` gets the length of the string.

Comment: Readability level 9999999 (y) :)

Comment: Would you please explain what's happening here?

Comment: But for string `a0bb`, it should return -1.

Comment: @roger_that Why is that? How can a length be -1?

Comment: @Gabriel: yeah my bad. I was suppose to put an empty check to return -1 as the requirement.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you split your String to have an array of strings without digit:

```
yourString.split("[0-9]")
```

Then iterate over this array (says array a) to get the longest string that contains one Upper case character:

```
a[i].matches("[a-z]*[A-Z]{1}[a-z]*");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple array. The algorithm to use would be a dynamic sliding window. Here is an example of a static sliding window: [What is a Sliding Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8269916/what-is-sliding-window-algorithm-examples)

**The algorithm should be as follows:**

Keep track of 2 indexes of the array of `char`. These 2 indexes will be referred to as `front` and `back` here, representing the front and back of the array.

Have an `int` (I'll name it `up` here) to keep track of the number of upper case `char`.

Set all to 0.

Use a while loop that terminates if `front > N` where `N` is the number of `char` given.

If the next char is not a number, add 1 to `front`. Then check if that `char` is upper case. If so, add 1 to `up`.

If `up` is at least 1, update the maximum length if necessary.

If the next char is a number, continue checking the following `char` if they are also numbers. Set `front` to the first index where the `char` is not a number and `back` to `front-1`.

Output the maximum length.

Answer (score 1):

You can use my solution which runs in O(n) time and finds the longest part without any digit and with a capital letter:

```
    String testString = "skjssldfkjsakdfjlskdssfkjslakdfiop7adfaijsldifjasdjfil8klsasdfŞdijpfjapodifjpoaidjfpoaidjpfi9a";

    int startIndex = 0;
    int longestStartIndex = 0;
    int endIndex = 0;
    int index = 0;
    int longestLength = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    boolean foundUpperCase = false;

    while(index <= testString.length()) {
        if (index == testString.length() || Character.isDigit(testString.charAt(index))) {
            if (foundUpperCase && index > startIndex && index - startIndex > longestLength) {
                longestLength = index - startIndex;
                endIndex = index;
                longestStartIndex = startIndex;
            }
            startIndex = index + 1;
            foundUpperCase = false;
        } else if (Character.isUpperCase(testString.charAt(index))) {
            foundUpperCase = true;
        }
        index++;
    }

    System.out.println(testString.substring(longestStartIndex, endIndex));
```

Comment: You should maybe check out the Javadoc for [`java.lang.Character`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html). There are a whole bunch of `isSomething` methods, e.g. `isUpperCase`, which is much easier and faster to use than your `isCharUpperCase` method; and `isDigit`, which covers a broader range of digits than just 0-9. Plus, `if (condition) return true; else return false;` is the same as `return condition;`.

Comment: Thank you very much @AndyTurner, that boolean if-else structure is the fault of mine that I do every time, now updated :). I always come across with the character problems every time I build a project so wanted to use a general upper case finder for the letter by using the regex literal which I used before, also you are right about that numbers too, I will update that part, thanks again :) Bu you know, the most important thing here is the algorithm in the iteration ;)

Answer (score 0):

I am using modification of Kadane algorithm to search the required password length. You may use isNumeric() and isCaps() function or include inline if statements. I have shown below with functions.

```
public boolean isNumeric(char x){
    return (x>='0'&&x<='9');
}
public boolean isCaps(char x){
    return (x>='A'&&x<='Z');
}
public int maxValidPassLen(String a)
{
   int max_so_far = 0, max_ending_here = 0;
   boolean cFlag = false;
   int max_len = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++)
   {
       max_ending_here = max_ending_here + 1;
       if (isCaps(a.charAt(i))){
           cFlag = true;
       }
       if (isNumeric(a.charAt(i))){
           max_ending_here = 0;
           cFlag = false;
       }
       else if (max_so_far<max_ending_here){
           max_so_far = max_ending_here;
       }
       if(cFlag&&max_len<max_so_far){
           max_len = max_so_far;
       }
   }
   return max_len;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Note: you don't need to cast a `char` before comparing to `int`: it is automatically widened. Also, you can use `'0'` and `'9'` instead of 48 and 57; it just makes it clear what these magic numbers are. Also `if (condition) return true; return false;` is the same as `return condition;`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regular expressions. Just use a few integers to act as index pointers into the string:

```
int i = 0;
int longestStart = 0;
int longestEnd = 0;
while (i < s.length()) {
  // Skip past all the digits.
  while (i < s.length() && Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i))) {
    ++i;
  }

  // i now points to the start of a substring
  // or one past the end of the string.
  int start = i;

  // Keep a flag to record if there is an uppercase character.
  boolean hasUppercase = false;

  // Increment i until you hit another digit or the end of the string.
  while (i < s.length() && !Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i))) {
    hasUppercase |= Character.isUpperCase(s.charAt(i));
    ++i;
  }

  // Check if this is longer than the longest so far.
  if (hasUppercase && i - start > longestEnd - longestStart) {
    longestEnd = i;
    longestStart = start;
  }
}
String longest = s.substring(longestStart, longestEnd);
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](http://ideone.com/2Fx9CJ)

Whilst more verbose than regular expressions, this has the advantage of not creating any unnecessary objects: the only object created is the longest string, right at the end.

Comment: How did you put that "Ideone demo" button?

Comment: Using the `<kbd></kbd>` tags.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of good answers here but thought it might be of interest to add one that uses Java 8 streams:

```
IntStream.range(0, s.length()).boxed()
    .flatMap(b -> IntStream.range(b + 1, s.length())
        .mapToObj(e -> s.substring(b, e)))
    .filter(t -> t.codePoints().noneMatch(Character::isDigit))
    .filter(t -> t.codePoints().filter(Character::isUpperCase).count() == 1)
    .mapToInt(String::length).max();
```

If you wanted the string (rather than just the length), then the last line can be replaced with:

```
    .max(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length));
```

Which returns an `Optional<String>`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `Streams` and `Optionals`:

```
public static String getBestPassword(String password) throws Exception {
    if (password == null) {
        throw new Exception("Invalid password");
    }
    Optional<String> bestPassword = Stream.of(password.split("[0-9]"))
            .filter(TypeErasure::containsCapital)
            .sorted((o1, o2) -> o1.length() > o2.length() ? 1 : 0)
            .findFirst();

    if (bestPassword.isPresent()) {
        return bestPassword.get();
    } else {
        throw new Exception("No valid password");
    }
}

/**
 * Returns true if word contains capital
 */
private static boolean containsCapital(String word) {
    return word.chars().anyMatch(Character::isUpperCase);
}
```

Be sure to write some unit tests

Answer (score 0):

```
public String pass(String str){
    int length = 0;
    boolean uppercase = false;
    String s= "";

    String d= "";

    for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++){
        if(Character.isUpperCase(str.charAt(i)) == true){
        uppercase = true;
        s = s+str.charAt(i);

        }else if(Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i)) == true ){
            if(uppercase == true && s.length()>length){
            d = s;
            s = "";   
            length = s.length();
            uppercase = false;   
            }   
        }else if(i==str.length()-1&&Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i))==false){
        s = s + str.charAt(i);
        if(uppercase == true && s.length()>length){
            d = s;
            s = "";   
            length = s.length();
           uppercase = false;
        }


        }else{
        s = s+str.charAt(i);
        }
   }
  return d;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution with Scala

```
 def solution(str: String): Int = {
      val strNoDigit = str.replaceAll("[0-9]", "-")
      strAlphas = strNoDigit.split("-")

      Try(strAlphas.filter(_.trim.find(_.isUpper).isDefined).maxBy(_.size))
      .toOption
      .map(_.length)
      .getOrElse(-1)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using tail recursion in Scala

```
    def solution2(str: String): Int = {

    val subSt = new ListBuffer[Char]

       def checker(str: String): Unit = {
          if (str.nonEmpty) {
        val s = str.head
        if (!s.isDigit) {
          subSt += s
        } else {
          subSt += '-'
        }
        checker(str.tail)
      }
    }

    checker(str)

    if (subSt.nonEmpty) {
      val noDigitStr = subSt.mkString.split("-")
      Try(noDigitStr.filter(s => s.nonEmpty && s.find(_.isUpper).isDefined).maxBy(_.size))
        .toOption
        .map(_.length)
        .getOrElse(-1)
    } else {
      -1
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] s = testString.split("[0-9]");
int length = 0;
int index = -1;
for(int i=0; i< s.length; i++){
    if(s[i].matches("[a-z]*.*[A-Z].*[a-z]*")){
        if(length <= s[i].length()){
            length = s[i].length();
            index = i;
        }
    }
}
if(index >= 0){
    System.out.println(s[index]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a dynamic programming problem. You can solve this yourself using a matrix. It is easy enough. Just give it a try. Take the characters of the password as the rows and columns of the matrix. Add the diagonals if the current character appended to the last character forms a valid password. Start with the smallest valid password as the initial condition.

Answer (score 0):

I think this solution takes care of all the possible corner cases. It passed all the test cases in an Online Judge. It is a dynamic sliding window `O(n)` solution.

```
public class LongestString {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // String testString = "AabcdDefghIjKL0";
        String testString = "a0bb";

        int startIndex = 0, endIndex = 0;
        int previousUpperCaseIndex = -1;
        int maxLen = 0;

        for (; endIndex < testString.length(); endIndex++) {
            if (Character.isUpperCase(testString.charAt(endIndex))) {
                if (previousUpperCaseIndex > -1) {
                    maxLen = Math.max(maxLen, endIndex - startIndex);
                    startIndex = previousUpperCaseIndex + 1;
                }
                previousUpperCaseIndex = endIndex;
            } else if (Character.isDigit(testString.charAt(endIndex))) {
                if (previousUpperCaseIndex > -1) {
                    maxLen = Math.max(maxLen, endIndex - startIndex);
                }
                startIndex = endIndex + 1;
                previousUpperCaseIndex = -1;
            }
        }
        if (previousUpperCaseIndex > -1)
            maxLen = Math.max(maxLen, endIndex - startIndex);
        System.out.println(maxLen);
    }}
```

Comment: @roger_that I solved it for at most 1 uppercase character. I checked the question now. I will modify the code according to that.

Comment: Thanks roger_that. I have modified my code. Kindly let me know, if any more test cases fails.

Answer (score 0):

//easiest way to do it:

```
String str = "a0Ba12hgKil8oPlk";
        String[] str1 = str.split("[0-9]+");
        List<Integer> in = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < str1.length; i++) {
            if (str1[i].matches("(.+)?[A-Z](.+)?")) {
                in.add(str1[i].length());
            } else {
                System.out.println(-1);
            }
        }
        Collections.sort(in);
        System.out.println("string : " + in.get(in.size() - 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution with c#. I tested a range of strings and it gave me the correct value. Used Split. No Regex or Substrings. Let me know if it works; open to improvements and corrections.

```
public static int validPassword(string str)
    {
        List<int> strLength = new List<int>();
        if (!(str.All(Char.IsDigit)))
        {
            //string str = "a0Bb";
            string[] splitStrs = str.Split(new char[] { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' });


            //check if each string contains a upper case
            foreach (string s in splitStrs)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine(s);
                if (s.Any(char.IsUpper) && s.Any(char.IsLower) || s.Any(char.IsUpper))
                {
                    strLength.Add(s.Length);
                }
            }

            if (strLength.Count == 0)
            {
                return -1;
            }

            foreach (int i in strLength)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine(i);

            }
            return strLength.Max();
        }


        else
        {
            return -1;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function ValidatePassword(password){
    var doesContainNumber = false;
    var hasUpperCase = false;

    for(var i=0;i<password.length;i++){
        if(!isNaN(password[i]))
            doesContainNumber = true;
        if(password[i] == password[i].toUpperCase())
            hasUpperCase = true;
    }

    if(!doesContainNumber && hasUpperCase)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

function GetLongestPassword(inputString){
    var longestPassword = "";
    for(var i=0;i<inputString.length-1;i++)
    {
        for (var j=i+1;j<inputString.length;j++)
        {
            var substring = inputString.substring(i,j+1);
            var isValid = ValidatePassword(substring);
            if(isValid){
                if(substring.length > longestPassword.length)
                {
                    longestPassword = substring;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if(longestPassword == "")
    {
        return "No Valid Password found";
    }
    else
    {
        return longestPassword;
    }
}
```