# Frequent words in Python

Tags: python, bioinformatics, string-matching

How can I write a code to find the most frequent 2-mer of "GATCCAGATCCCCATAC".
I have written this code but it seems that I am wrong, please help in correcting me.

```
def PatternCount(Pattern, Text):
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(Text)-len(Pattern)+1):
        if Text[i:i+len(Pattern)] == Pattern:
            count = count+1
    return count
```

This code prints the most frequent k-mer in a string but it don't give me the 
2-mer in the given string.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include possible values for `Pattern` and `Text`. Hint: In Python, function and variable names don't start with an uppercase letter. Those are reserved for class names.

Comment: Your question assumes that we know what a 2-mer is.  Unfortunately, without knowing what a 2-mer is, it's really hard to tell you how to find the most frequent one.

Comment: A 2-mer is basically the most frequent 2 words which is repeated in the given string,generally we can call it k-mer.For example, "ACTAT" is a most frequent 5-mer for Text = "ACAACTATGCATACTATCGGGAACTATCCT".

Comment: That is the code which I have written for finding the most frequent repeated word in a string ,e.g,in "CGATATATCCATAG",the most frequent word is "ATA",so that is the pattern and the given string is the Text.

Comment: I have written that code for finding the k-mer but I don't know that this code will help me in the given question,so please me in correcting me.

Comment: @shahzadfida -- Ok... If I have the string `AAAA`, is the 2-mer `AA` repeated 2 times or 3 times?  i.e. can they overlap?

Comment: @shahzadfida Look at my answer it's quite simple and it show you how it deals with overlaping k-mer (i.e. it counts them)

Comment: yes,they can overlap.It is 3-mer.

Comment: @shahzadfida What about accepting an answer ? haha

Answer (score 7):

You can first define a function to get all the k-mer in your string :

```
def get_all_k_mer(string, k=1):
   length = len(string)
   return [string[i: i+ k] for i in xrange(length-k+1)]
```

Then you can use `collections.Counter` to count the repetition of each k-mer:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> s = 'GATCCAGATCCCCATAC'
>>> Counter(get_all_k_mer(s, k=2))
```

Ouput :

```
Counter({'AC': 1,
         'AG': 1,
         'AT': 3,
         'CA': 2,
         'CC': 4,
         'GA': 2,
         'TA': 1,
         'TC': 2})
```

Another example :

```
>>> s = "AAAAAA"
>>> Counter(get_all_k_mer(s, k=3))
```

Output :

```
Counter({'AAA': 4})
# Indeed : AAAAAA
           ^^^     -> 1st time
            ^^^    -> 2nd time
             ^^^   -> 3rd time
               ^^^ -> 4th time
```

Comment: Sorry about the downvote,but  I correct the code in python.as in python 3 there is no xrange,it is simply range.

Comment: `range` and `xrange` will give same results but they are not same objects. `xrange` is kind of a generator while `range` creates a list directly in memory. So if you have a very long string you should preferably use `xrange`

Comment: Pythonic.  I would mention something about `xrange` being in Python 2 and resolving it with `range` in 3.

Answer (score 3):

In general, when I want to count things with python I use a `Counter`

```
from itertools import tee
from collections import Counter

dna = "GATCCAGATCCCCATAC"
a, b = tee(iter(dna), 2)
_ = next(b)
c = Counter(''.join(l) for l in zip(a,b))
print(c.most_common(1))
```

This prints `[('CC', 4)]`, a list of the `1` most common 2-mers in a tuple with their count in the string.

In fact, we can generalize this to the find the most common n-mer for a given `n`.

```
from itertools import tee, islice
from collections import Counter

def nmer(dna, n):
    iters = tee(iter(dna), n)
    iters = [islice(it, i, None) for i, it in enumerate(iters)]
    c = Counter(''.join(l) for l in zip(*iters))
    return c.most_common(1)
```

Comment: You shouldn't need a `tee` here.  That'll double the intermediate storage that is necessary -- However, strings can be iterated over multiple times so you can just do `a, b = iter(dna), iter(dna)`.

Comment: I have problem in understanding the above code.Please elaborate it as I do not know for what a,b,c and _ stand.

Comment: But if we edit the code to a ,b = iter(dna), iter(dna), It still give the same result.

Comment: @shahzadfida `a` and `b` don't stand for anything, they're just variable names.  `c` stands for `Counter`.  As @mgilson points out, this is an overly complex solution if you are guaranteed to have input in the form of strings.  If your input could come from another iterator, like a generator, this solution doesn't rely on indexing and slicing, which some types don't support

Comment: @shahzadfida `Counter` is a subtype of `dict`.

Comment: Please use simple code as I am learning bioinformatics and I have a little background in programming. But "thanks alot" for your reply and time.

Comment: @shahzadfida the other option is `defaultdict(int)`, which isn't more clear for a beginner.  `Counter` is the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a simple approach, consider a [sliding window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8269916/what-is-sliding-window-algorithm-examples) technique.  An implementation is available in [more_itertools](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.windowed), so you don't have to make one yourself.  This is easy to use if you `pip install more_itertools`.

**Simple Example**

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> import more_itertools

>>> s = "GATCCAGATCCCCATAC"
>>> Counter(more_itertools.windowed(s, 2))
Counter({('A', 'C'): 1,
         ('A', 'G'): 1,
         ('A', 'T'): 3,
         ('C', 'A'): 2,
         ('C', 'C'): 4,
         ('G', 'A'): 2,
         ('T', 'A'): 1,
         ('T', 'C'): 2})
```

The above example demonstrates what little is required to get most of the information you want using `windowed` and `Counter`.

**Description**

A "window" or container of length `k=2` is sliding across the sequence one stride at a time (e.g. `step=1`).  Each new group is added as a key to the `Counter` dictionary.  For each occurrence, the tally is incremented.  The final `Counter` object primarily reports all tallies and includes other [helpful features](https://pymotw.com/2/collections/counter.html).

**Final Solution**

If actual string pairs is important, that is simple too.  We will make a general function that groups the strings and works for any k mers:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> import more_itertools

>>> def count_mers(seq, k=1):
...     """Return a counter of adjacent mers."""
...     return Counter(("".join(mers) for mers in more_itertools.windowed(seq, k)))

>>> s = "GATCCAGATCCCCATAC"
>>> count_mers(s, k=2)
Counter({'AC': 1,
         'AG': 1,
         'AT': 3,
         'CA': 2,
         'CC': 4,
         'GA': 2,
         'TA': 1,
         'TC': 2})
```

Comment: @MMF it's awesome.  Take a look

Comment: Are you asking where are the numbers coming from?  They are the sum occurrences of adjacent letters in the string from left to right.  How the keys appear in any dictionary is unordered (except Python 3.6).

Comment: more_itertools return with an error and if we simply import itertool,it still don't do the job for us,It returns with the result that" module itertools has no attribute as window"?

Comment: This is a separate package from `itertools`.  In your command prompt, you will want to `pip install more_itertools` for the more recent version.  Once installed, then go to your python session and `import more_itertools`.  You may have to restart your session.