# How to merge elements in list in python with condition?

Tags: python, list

I am having a hard time to find a solution to merge two different type of element within the list.

```
list_i = ['teacher', '10', 'student', '100', 'principle', '2']
```

Result:

```
list_1 = ['teacher:10', 'student:100', 'principle:2']
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Where are you stuck exactly? iterating by 2? working with strings?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will work:

```
[list_i[i] + ":" + list_i[i+1] for i in range(0, len(list_i), 2)]
```

This produces:

```
['teacher:10', 'student:100', 'principle:2']
```

Answer (score 5):

Use following code

```
[':'.join(item) for item in zip(list_i[::2],list_i[1::2])]
```

This will just slice the list in 2 parts and joins them with zip

Answer (score 0):

Using [`more_itertools`](https://github.com/erikrose/more-itertools), a third-party library, you can apply a [sliding window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8269916/what-is-sliding-window-algorithm-examples) technique:

```
> pip install more_itertools
```

**Code**

```
import more_itertools as mit


iterable = ['teacher', '10', 'student', '100', 'principle', '2']

[":".join(i) for i in mit.windowed(iterable, 2, step=2)]
# ['teacher:10', 'student:100', 'principle:2']
```

Alternatively apply the `grouper` [itertools recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes), which is also implemented in [`more_itertools`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html).

```
[":".join(i) for i in mit.grouper(2, iterable)]
# ['teacher:10', 'student:100', 'principle:2']
```