# Create circular iterator from incremental start position

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, offset

OK so I want to create within a loop iterator in index that goes like this

```
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8][1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,0][2,3,4,5,6,7,8,0,1][3,4,5,6,7,8,0,1,2]...[8,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

where the maximum value may be 8 or another number.

so far I have some code that doesn't work.

```
a = ['l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t'] #len(a) = 9
b = [[]] *len(a)
c = [[]] *len(a)
for offset_index in range(len(a)):
    b[offset_index] = []
    c[offset_index] = []
    for i in range(offset_index, len(a) - offset_index, 1):
        b[offset_index].append(i)
        c[offset_index].append(a[i])
print b
```

> [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [3, 4, 5], [4], [], [], [], []]

I can see it's a problem with the 2nd range function, but can't imagine a neat fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my code:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
for slice_index in range(0, len(a)):
    print (a[slice_index::] + a[:slice_index:])
```

> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>   [2, 3, 4, 5, 1]
>   [3, 4, 5, 1, 2]
>   [4, 5, 1, 2, 3]
>   [5, 1, 2, 3, 4]

**Explanation:** `a[slice_index::]` gives the part of array where index >= slice_index. Same for the other.

Comment: Just awesome.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

#### `itertools.cycle` + `itertools.islice`

Efficient cycling and iteration — no copies were harmed in the process of writing this solution.

```
from itertools import cycle, islice

l = list(range(9))
repeats = 8

[list(islice(cycle(l), i, len(l) + i)) for i in range(repeats)]

[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0],
 [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 1],
 [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 1, 2],
 [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 1, 2, 3],
 [5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
 [6, 7, 8, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 [7, 8, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]
```

Or, if you don't want to preserve the indices:

```
for i in range(repeats):
    idx = list(islice(cycle(l), i, len(l) + i)) 
    ... # do something with idx
```

---

#### List Comprehension

The choice of users looking for performance.

```
[l[i:] + l[:i] for i in range(repeats)]

[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0],
 [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 1],
 [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 1, 2],
 [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 1, 2, 3],
 [5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
 [6, 7, 8, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 [7, 8, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]
```

Comment: This is the best answer if I need to preserve the index for later.  Thanks.

Comment: @Joylove Are your arrays large? In that case, my option 1 may be more efficient than the other answers. I've added a version that does not preserve the indices. Check it out :)

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
b = []
for i in range(len(a)):
    b.append([])
    for j in range(len(a)):
        b[i].append(a[(i+j)%len(a)])

print b
```

Answer (score 1):

[`more_itertools.circular_shifts`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.circular_shifts) implements [circular shifts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_shift), a type of [cyclic permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_permutation).

**Code**

```
import more_itertools as mit


iterable = range(9)

# Option 1
mit.circular_shifts(iterable)
```

Output

```
[(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8),
 (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0),
 (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 1),
 (3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 1, 2),
 (4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 1, 2, 3),
 (5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4),
 (6, 7, 8, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
 (7, 8, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
 (8, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)]
```

---

**Alternatives**

Using [sliding windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8269916/what-is-sliding-window-algorithm-examples) via the same [third-party library](https://github.com/erikrose/more-itertools):

```
import itertools as it


# Option 2
list(it.islice(mit.windowed(it.cycle(iterable), n=len(iterable)), len(iterable)))

# Option 3
list(mit.windowed(mit.ncycles(iterable, n=2), n=len(iterable)))[:-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> L = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
>>> [[L[i-j] for i in range(len(L))] for j in range(len(L), 0, -1)]
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
 ['b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a'],
 ['c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b'],
 ['d', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c'],
 ['e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd']]
```

Comment: Please add some explenation to your answer.

Comment: @AndréKool, it's similar to Dawit's answer, but uses a mixture of positive and negative indices instead of modulus. Replace `L[i-j]` with `i-j` to see the indices that are generated.