# Finding multiple occurences of a string within a string using Python (adjacent)

Tags: python-3.x

I recently started to learn Python programming. It goes as following:

For `s = 'xasdkbobobasdvobob'`, find the number of occurences of 'bob' in s.

I've been able to write a code that will give me an output of 2 however the answer I'm looking for is 3.

Comment: Please show the code you have written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are regular expression-based solutions to this [elsewhere on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616822/python-regex-find-all-overlapping-matches), but you can do this by iteratively finding each "bob" without the need for REs:

```
s = 'xasdkbobobasdvobob'
pos = -1
count = 0
while True:
    pos = s.find('bob', pos + 1) # search from the character after the start of the last find
    if pos > -1: # found an instance
        count += 1
    else: # no more instances
        break
print count
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using the new Python regex module, which supports overlapping matches.

```
import re
s = 'xasdkbobobasdvobob'
print(len(list(re.finditer('(?=bob)', s))))
```

Python regex module

> https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex

Answer (score 0):

*Option 1*

Use the [`regex` module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/):

```
import regex


len(regex.findall(r"bob", s, overlapped=True))
# 3

sum(1 for _ in regex.finditer(r"bob", s, overlapped=True))
# 3
```

---

*Option 2*

Apply the sliding [window algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8269916/what-is-sliding-window-algorithm-examples).  Here we use the third-party tool [`more_itertools.windowed`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.windowed):

```
import more_itertools as mit


sum(1 for w in mit.windowed(s, 3) if w == tuple("bob"))
# 3
```

Install the [library](https://github.com/erikrose/more-itertools) via `> pip install more_itertools`.