# Generate only continuous combinations of a list of numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-itertools

I have a list in python [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]. I want to generate all possible combinations of length 2, 3, 4 and 5. I have used itertools.combinations to generate the combinations but it doesn't generate continuous combinations only. For example, length 2 combinations should be only [1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5], [5, 6]. Is there any faster way to generate than the following code?

```
for start, end in combinations(range(len(lst)), 2):
    if end - start <= 4 and end-start >= 1:
        print(lst[start:end+1])
```

Comment: that are not really combinations, you want consecutive numbers from a list of size N

Comment: The combinations of length 3 are [1,2,3], [2,3,4],[3,4,5],[4,5,6]

Comment: @Netwave Yes, indeed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need [`combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) at all. What you want looks more like a [sliding window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8269916/what-is-sliding-window-algorithm-examples).

```
for i in range(2, 6):
    for j in range(len(lst) - i + 1):
        print(lst[j:j + i])
```

Comment: Thanks @Delgan. Works like charm!

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over the list as following:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
for i in range(2, len(a)):
    for j in range(len(a)-i + 1):
        print(a[j:j+i])
    print()
```

The trick here is that `a[j:j+i]` returns the list from j, up until j+i.

Putting this into a function form:

```
def continuous(lst, length):
     slices = []
     for j in range(len(lst)-length + 1):
         slices.append(a[j:j+length])
     return slices
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the list in the following method

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ,6]

def continuous(lst, length):
    result = []
    for i in range (0, len(lst)-length):
        entry = []
        for j in range (0, length):
            entry.append(lst[i+j])
        result.append(entry)
    return result

print(continuous(lst, 2))
```

or if you are just looking to print it line by line

```
def continuous(lst, length):
    for i in range (0, len(lst)-length):
        entry = []
        for j in range (0, length):
            entry.append(lst[i+j])
        print(entry)
```