# Generate adjacent elements from List

Tags: python, python-3.x, sliding-window

I want to generate contiguous sliding window from a list

```
nums = [1,2,3,4,10]

####O/P 
[[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 10]]
```

My code so far -

```
>>> num_list = [1,2,3,4,10]
>>> 
>>> res = []
>>> n = len(num_list)
>>> 
>>> for i in range(n):
...     imm = []
...     for j in range(i,i+1):
...             imm += [num_list[i], num_list[j]]
...     res += [imm]
... 
>>> res
[[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4], [10, 10]]
```

I m beginner in python , the `num_list` is a just fraction of the actual list, its longer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is a [sliding window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8269916/what-is-sliding-window-algorithm-examples)

You can try the below function , it also reduces your Time Complexity from O(N^2) to O(N)

Other resources

- [Link - 1](https://janac.medium.com/what-is-the-sliding-window-algorithm-f9fcfe92b853)
- [Link - 2](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/43303/what-is-a-contiguous-subarray#:%7E:text=1%20Answer-,1,element%20and%20everything%20between%20them.)

```
l = [1,2,3,4,10]

def divide_chunks_contigious(in_arr,chunk):
    n = len(in_arr)
    i = 0
    while i + chunk <= n:
        i += 1
        yield in_arr[i-1:i+chunk-1]

>>> list(divide_chunks_contigious(l,2))
[[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 10]]
```

Also the problem with your code can be resolved by initilizing `j` from `i+1` till `i+2` , but over long sequences it would be slower

```
for i in range(n-1):
    imm = []
    for j in range(i+1,i+2):
        imm += [num_list[i],num_list[j]]
    res += [imm]

>>> res
[[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 10]]
```

Comment: The time complexity of the code in question is also O(N) as the second for loop will iterate only once so, O(N*1) isn't it?

Comment: This is valid when chunk size is 2 (adjacent element) , What happens when the chunk size is greater than 2 , the second loop will become longer

Comment: if the chunk size increases then yes, But here chunk size is hardcoded to 1 though So, the time complexity is O(N) right?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to create a list of consecutive pairs from the list by passing the original list and a slice of the list offset by 1:

```
list(zip(num_list, num_list[1:]))
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code in second for loop

```py
for  j in range(i, i+1):
    print(j)
# j = i
```

that's why your result is not right you can use this below code

```py
n = [1,2,3,4,5]
ans = []
for i in range(len(n)-1):
    ans.append([n[i], n[i+1]])
print(ans)
# ans = [[1,2], [2,3],[3,4],[4,5]]
```