# Longest substring that appears at least twice in O(n.logn)

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, substring, longest-substring

**Problem:**

Given a String S of N characters `(N <= 200 000)`, find the length of the longest substring that appears at least twice (the substrings can overlap).

**My solution:**

Here's what i've tried:

```
int main()
{
    std::string s;
    std::cin >> s;
    int max = 0;
    typedef std::string::const_iterator sit;
    sit end = s.end();
    for(sit it1 = s.begin(); it1 != end; ++it1)
        for(sit it2 = it1 + 1; it2 != end; ++it2)
            max = std::max(max, std::mismatch(it1, it1 + (end - it2), it2).first - it1);
    std::cout << max;
}
```

**Question:**

However, the above solution will get TLE as it runs in O(n^3). Is there any ways to improve it so it can run in O(n.logn)?

Comment: *"as it runs in `O(n^2)`"*. it is `O(n^3)`, you forget to count `std::mismatch`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suffix tree is an overkill for this problem. In fact, binary search suffices and the implementation is much easier.

### Idea

The idea is simple: If there exists a duplicated substring of length N (N > 1), there must also exists one of length N - 1. Therefore, if we let f(x) to denote a function that returns true if there exists a duplicated substring of length x, f(x) will be a monotonic function, which allows a binary search solution.

### Implementation

Binary search on the length of the longest duplicated substring and apply [sliding windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8269916/what-is-sliding-window-algorithm-examples) to check if a given length is possible. Use string hashing to check for duplicate.
Complexity: N log N

Comment: Binary tree for duplicate checking will not work because each comparison takes up to O(N) so the total is ≥ O(N²).

Answer (score 4):

> find the length of the longest substring that appears at least twice
> (the substrings can overlap)

This problem is also commonly known as [Longest repeated substring problem](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/suffix-tree-application-3-longest-repeated-substring/).
It can be solved in linear time with a suffix tree.

To solve this problem:

1. Add a special character '$' to the given string S),
2. build a suffix tree from S ;
3. the longest repeated substring of S is indicated by the deepest internal node in the suffix tree, where depth is measured by the number of characters traversed from the root.

Time complexity:

- Suffix tree takes  O(nlog(k))) time, where k is the size of the alphabet (if k is considered to be a constant, the asymptotic behaviour is linear)
- tree traversal(for finding longest repeated substring) can be done in O(n) time