# Draw a rough line according a lot of data By javascript

Tags: javascript

Here.

I got a lot of data, and draw a real line. But, I want to draw a rough one(as the red one), how can i do that. Thanks.

[image]

Addition: Image that the x axis is time, and y axis is `mv`, the real line frequency is 50 Hz [according the time between begin and end point of red line]. And the rough one, I should get 20 Hz [according the red line]. How could i do that.

Comment: I compare moving average, gaussian filter and triangle filter. And they help me a lot in some way.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a sliding window as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8269948/4874075

Instead of printing the exact values, you can for instance use the average of a value and its neighbor values.