# how to print the max sequence of a given vector (possible values 1 and 0) with the property that are different and the number of the max sequence c++

Tags: c++, algorithm

Let's say I have a vector v with random 1 and 0.

```
std::vector<int> v = {1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1};
```

I want to find out the max sequence with the property v[i] != v[i-1]. Basically the numbers need to be different. In this example the max sequence is 4 (1, 0, 1, 0) from position v[0] to v[3]. There is also (0,1,0,1) from position v[4] to v[7]. There are 2 max sequences so the final output should look like this:

`4 2`

Where 4 is the max sequence and 2 the numbers of max sequences.
Let's take another example:

```
std::vector<int> v2 = {1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0};
```

The output here should be:
`6 1`

The max sequence starts from v[4] to v[9]. There is only one max sequence so it will print 1 this time.

I tried to solve this using a for loop:
n - number of integers in the vector
k - number of different integers in vector
maxk - the max sequence
many - how many max sequence are

```
for(int i{1}; i < n; i++) {
    if(v[i] != v[i-1]) {
        k++;
        if(k > maxk) {
            maxk = k;
        }
    }
    else {
        if(k == maxk) {
            many++;
        }
        else {
            many = 1;
        }
        k = 1;
    }
}
```

But if you give it a vector like {1, 0, 0} it will not work. Can someone give me a tip of how this problem can be solved? Sorry for my bad english

Comment: You should think about the solution using paper and pencil before writing any code.  If you did that, then the program becomes simple -- just mimic the steps you wrote down on paper.

Comment: I did that, but for me is still pretty unclear. Can you be a little bit more explicit?

Comment: Also this is more an "algorithm" question (tag) then a C++ one. Looks like a candidate for [sliding window technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8269916/what-is-sliding-window-algorithm-examples)

Comment: What is the initial values of many? I think you cannot increment many in the else branch when k == maxk, since k is also equal to maxk, if the current sequence larger is the largest.

Comment: The `if(k == maxk)` conditional should be part of the `v[i] != v[i-1]` case. `many = 1;` should happen when `k > maxk`. So the `v[i] == v[i-1]` case should only have `k = 1;`

Answer (score 0):

First, sequence isn't the right word.  A sequence can jump past elements.  You mean a subarray.

Second, you talk about arrays with 0 and 1 in them, then give an example with 2.  Do you want to not count subarrays with 2?  Or count them? In other words if the input is `[1, 2, 2]` are you expecting an answer of `1 1` or `2 1`?'.

That said, just make an array of where the best current subarray begins.  For your first example that array would look like this:

```
1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1
0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 4
```

And then a linear scan finds that you have a group of 4 starting at index 0, and another group of 4 starting at index 4.

For your next example,

```
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0
0, 0, 0, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4
```

And you have a group of 3 starting at index 0, 1 starting at 3, and 6 starting at 4.  So we've found the 1 group of 6.

For your last example, what you'd get would depend on the answer you want.

I'll leave coding this to you.