# Need explanation on one awesome solution found for Leetcode 1493

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, sliding-window

I am looking at solutions for LeetCode problem [1493. Longest Subarray of 1's After Deleting One Element](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-subarray-of-1s-after-deleting-one-element/):

> Given a binary array `nums`, you should delete one element from it.
>
> Return *the size of the longest non-empty subarray containing only 1's in the resulting array*. Return 0 if there is no such subarray.
>
> #### Example 1
>
> **Input:** `nums = [1,1,0,1]`
> **Output:** 3
> **Explanation:** After deleting the number in position 2, `[1,1,1]` contains 3 numbers with value of 1's.
>
> #### Example 2
>
> **Input:** `nums = [0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1]`
> **Output:** 5
> **Explanation:** After deleting the number in position 4, `[0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1]` longest subarray with value of 1's is `[1,1,1,1,1]`.
>
> #### Constraints:
>
> - `1 <= nums.length <= 105`
> - `nums[i]` is either 0 or 1.

I found a super clean solution in the submission pool, which I believe to be beneficial if I can understand how it worked, but I just can't.

```py
class Solution(object):
    def longestSubarray(self, nums):
        ans = 0
        zero = 0
        left = 0
        for i, v in enumerate(nums):
            if v == 0:
                zero += 1
            if zero > 1:
                if nums[left] == 0:
                    zero -= 1
                left += 1
        return i - left
```

I think, from the return statement, it's clear that `left` is used to count the zeros from left, and the un-counted 1.
I see how it tracks how many unused zeros on the left.
But how does it track the 1s that are not included?

And why this algorithm still works for when the longest subarray appears in the middle, as it continues further, passing beyond the longest subarray?

I guess I'm just confused here...

Comment: The code shown in your question does not work. e.g., for an input of [0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1] your result is 6 whereas it should be 5. Also, you'll get UnboundLocalError if you pass an empty list to longestSubarray()

Comment: @DarkKnight, it returns 5 for [0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1], and the constraints of the code challenge guarantee that the list is not empty (but this should have been mentioned in the question).

Comment: Apologies. Either the code has been edited since I tested it or I put in bad values

Answer (score 1):

This uses a [sliding window technique](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8269916/5459839), where the current window is identified with `nums[left:i]` at the start of every iteration.

We can identify the following loop invariants, when at the very *start* of the loop body:

- The size `i - left` is the size of the largest window in `nums[:i]` that includes at most one zero. It indicates that we previously encountered (somewhere) a window of the same size that had at most one zero, but we don't track at which index we found it.
- `zero` represents the number of zeroes in the current window `nums[left:i]`.

The current iteration will add `nums[i]` to the window, and if that keeps the number of zeroes in that window to at most one, we have a current "winner", and `left` is not incremented so that the window size increases. Otherwise it is not a winner, and `left` is incremented, aiming to keep the window size unchanged. During these actions `zero` is updated to make sure the second invariant is maintained.

After the loop has finished, we need to take the following into account:

We don't have the invariant there, because `i` did not increase to `len(nums)`, but remains equal to the last index of `nums`. This is something that is language specific. It happens to work like that in Python, but in other loop constructs or other languages, `i` could end up as equal to `len(nums)`. Anyway, here value `i - left` is one less than the "winner" we found. But this is exactly what we needed, because we *"...should delete one element from it"*.

One thing in all this that can be confusing is that the current window does not represent the window of interest, only the **size** of the window of interest. This algorithm doesn't care about where exactly that optimal window is located. It only looks further to find potential winners that are one unit larger.

To get some insight in how the code runs, it helped me to put this `print` in the code:

```
            if zero > 1:
                if nums[left] == 0:
                    zero -= 1
                left += 1
            else:  # We have an improvement!
                print(f"the current winner is window {left}:{i+1}: {nums[left:i+1]}")
```

I hope this clarifies it.