# Identifying the longest possible consecutive run in X cards given Y wildcards

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

I'm currently working on a problem, which states that I have X cards, and amongst those, X-Y cards are cards with integers on them, while Y cards are wildcards that can take on any integer values.

I'm trying to implement python code that can identify the longest possible consecutive run among the X cards.
(A run of length l is a sequence of l cards with the integers (a,a+1,a+2,…,a+l−1)for some integer a.)

```
def longest_run(X, Y, cards):
    cards.sort()

    longest_run_length = 1
    current_run_length = 1

    for i in range(1, X - Y):
        if cards[i] == cards[i - 1] + 1:
            current_run_length += 1
        elif cards[i] != cards[i - 1]:
            gap = cards[i] - cards[i - 1] - 1
            if Y >= gap:
                current_run_length += gap
                Y -= gap

        longest_run_length = max(longest_run_length, current_run_length)
   
    longest_run_length += Y

    
    return longest_run_length

# Sample Input
input_data = "11 2\n2 5 4 3 3 8 7 11 15"
X, Y = map(int, input_data.split("\n")[0].split())
cards = list(map(int, input_data.split("\n")[1].split()))

result = longest_run(X, Y, cards)
print(result)
```

I tried implementing this code, but there were various problems with it. Firstly, after identifying the gaps and filling them in with wildcards, my code did not continue searching for other numbers that it could add to the run. Secondly, since I want to find the longest run length possible, starting from the smallest card integer values may lead to incorrect solutions and using up all wildcards, while on the other hand if I started from another integer value I might've gotten a longer run.

Would appreciate any help on the matter, and thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

You have correctly identified the limitations of your code. It only looks at sequences that start at the least value in the input, but it is possible that the solution must start somewhere else. To consider those too, you could *reduce* the current window by subtracting the left side from it (one sequence and one gap), so you can recover some wildcards to be reused to extend more to the right and consider this as a competing alternative to the previous solution found. This is the [sliding window](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8269916/5459839) technique.

I would first transform the input to alternating sizes:

```
[size of sequence, size of gap], [size of sequence, size of gap], ...
```

Suggested code:

```
def longest_run(x, y, cards):
    if not cards:
        return y
    cards = sorted(set(cards))  # eliminate duplicates
    # turn into consecutive sequence-size and gap-size pairs
    sizes = [[1]]
    for prev, curr in zip(cards, cards[1:]):
        if curr > prev + 1:
            sizes[-1].append(curr - prev - 1)  # gap size
            sizes.append([1])                  # size of new sequence
        else:
            sizes[-1][0] += 1                  # update size of sequence
    # add closing
    sizes[-1].append(y)                        # gap size (infinity)
    
    # sliding window technique:
    wildcards = y   # currently available wildcards
    score = best = 0
    ahead = iter(sizes)  # iterator that runs ahead of loop iterator
    for seq_first, gap_first in sizes:
        # grow window to the right
        while wildcards:
            last = next(ahead, None)
            if not last:
                return best
            seq_last, gap_last = last
            score += seq_last + min(wildcards, gap_last)
            wildcards = max(0, wildcards - gap_last)
            best = max(score, best)
        # shrink window from the left
        wildcards = gap_first
        score -= seq_first + gap_first
    
    return best
```

NB: `x` is not used, as it seems to me it is the length of `cards`, i.e. all cards can be used if possible.