# How can I implement a linear time implementation of a function that counts the number of occurrences of a non-consecutive subsequence?

Tags: c++, string, char, nested-loops, function-definition

My Programming I class assigned an exercise in which we have to implement a function that counts the number of occurrences of a non-consecutive subsequence in a string. This is what we're asked to do:

> To begin with, you have to implement a function such that, given a string *s* and three different characters *c*<sub>1</sub>, *c*<sub>2</sub>, *c*<sub>3</sub> as parameters, returns how many times *c*<sub>1</sub>*c*<sub>2</sub>*c*<sub>3</sub> occurs in s as (non-consecutive) subsequence. In other words, it returns the number of triples of indexes (*i*<sub>1</sub>,*i*<sub>2</sub>,*i*<sub>3</sub>) holding *i*<sub>1</sub><*i*<sub>2</sub><*i*<sub>3</sub> and *s*[*i*<sub>1</sub>]=*c*<sub>1</sub>, *s*[*i*<sub>2</sub>]=*c*<sub>2</sub>, *s*[*i*<sub>3</sub>]=*c*<sub>3</sub>.

And this is the code I implemented:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int numberSubsequences(const string &s, char c1, char c2, char c3) {
    int count = 0;
    int lengthSequence = s.length();
    for ( int i = 0; i < lengthSequence - 2; ++i ) {
        if ( s[i] == c1 ) {
            for ( int j = i + 1; j < lengthSequence - 1; ++j ) {
                if ( s[j] == c2 ) {
                    for ( int k = j + 1; k < lengthSequence; ++k ) {
                        if ( s[k] == c3 ) {
                            count = count + 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

The problem is that I submitted this code and the submission program we use said that I exceeded the time limit for some private cases. Is there a way to simplify this function so that it passes all cases? Any help is appreciated. :)

Comment: *Is there a way to simplify this function* -- More than likely you need a better algorithm, not a "simplification" of the function you wrote.   Also, it is the simple functions, or approaches, that lead to non-optimal code, and to optimize requires more thought or more sophisticated approaches.

Comment: For example, [sliding window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8269916/what-is-sliding-window-algorithm-examples).

Answer (score 2):

In order to avoid entirely doing your homework for you, here is a version which handles the case of two characters rather than three:

```
int numberSubsequences(const string &s, char c1, char c2) {
    int count1 = 0;
    int count2 = 0;

    for (size_t ii = 0; ii < s.size(); ++ii) {
        if (s[ii] == c1)
            ++count1;
        if (s[ii] == c2)
            count2 += count1;
    }

    return count2;
}
```

The main idea is to scan the input string only once, which is the best "big O" possible for this problem.  At each position, we know how many times we have seen `c1`, and if we see `c2` we accumulate the count of `c1` which came before it.

Extending this to three or more characters is an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score -1):

We can mark the coordinates of the positions where c1, c2, and c3 appear. Then, for any c1 coordinate, we need to find how many c2 coordinates are to the right of that coordinate as c2 candidates for that c1 coordinate. Similarly, for each c2 candidate, we use the same method to find the number of c3 coordinates for that case.

Because we already have the coordinate information for c2, we can use binary search (or a similar algorithm, such as a red-black tree) to get this information. The same is true for c3. In this case, the time complexity of building the coordinates is O(N), and the search process is n * log(n) * log(n). You can try it and it should meet the time requirements

Refer to the following code:

```
int numberSubsequences(const string &s, char c1, char c2, char c3) {
    set<int> p1,p2,p3;
    for(int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++) {
        if(s[i] == c1) {
            p1.insert(i);
        } else if (s[i] == c2) {
            p2.insert(i);
        } else if (s[i] == c3) {
            p3.insert(i);
        }
    }   
    
    int r = 0;
    for(auto i : p1) {
        auto found = p2.upper_bound(i);     
        for(auto iter = found; iter != p2.end(); iter++) {
            auto found2 = p3.upper_bound(*iter);
            r += std::distance(found2, p3.end());
        }       
    }
    return r;
}
```

Comment: This is a pathologically bad use case for `std::set`: for each 4-byte integer you want to store it calls `malloc()` which is slow and takes 10x the memory of the actual integer being stored.  And the inserts are "sorting" the values even though we know every value inserted is the highest value seen so far.  Then you use `std::distance()` which is `O(n)` because you're using a tree.  You'd be much better off using vectors for `p1,p2,p3`.

Comment: Yes, I completely agree with you. However, I think OP's problem is that he is failing to meet the time limit requirement for leetcode-style problems. This is obviously because his time complexity is too high. My code examples are actually just to demonstrate an algorithm with a lower time complexity. Yes, if OP wants to achieve ultra-low latency, then he can continue to optimize his code as John suggested.

Comment: You say the triple-nested loop in your algorithm is `n * log(n) * log(n)`.  Are you sure about that?  It looks like you're counting `upper_bound()` as `log(n)` which is correct, but you're not counting the second `for` loop nor the `std::distance()` which are `O(n)`.  You also say it's `O(n)` for the first loop, but that's not true because `std::set::insert()` is `O(log n)` and you're doing that in a loop over `n`.